# Are emails susceptible to xss (and how to mitigate)?

Tags: php, email, xss, phpmailer

I will be using phpmailer to send an email.  Both the message (i.e. `$mail->MsgHTML`) and the subject (i.e. `$mail->Subject`) are based on user input.  Will either the subject or message pose a risk to the recipient?  I assume the subject might not be but the message will likely be.  Assuming I am correct, will HTMLPurifier be adequate for the message?

Comment: No modern mail client will execute JavaScript, so XSS isn't really a worry. There are other potential problems though, in particular [mail injection](http://securephpwiki.com/index.php/Email_Injection). But I believe PHPMailer is already protecting against that.

Comment: You should do some filtering with `strip_tags()` or HTMLPurifier though, to limit the input to an acceptable HTML subset.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  Am using HTMLPurifier on the message only and not the subject.  Seem adequate?

Comment: The subject is not vulnerable to anything like XSS unless the recipient is using a truly terrible client (like a web-based one displaying the subject without entity encoding, if such a client exists). PHPMailer is likely protecting against header injection, so I think you're fine.

Comment: I can confirm that PHPMailer protects against header injection.